# Enlarge a gtable inside a ggroup; R gWidgets

Tags: r, gwidgets

When I add a gtable inside a ggroup (using the RGtk2 guiToolkit) the gtable is very reduced, only 1 or 2 rows. Is there a solution to extend the gtable ?

Example :

```
library(gWidgets)
options("guiToolkit" = "RGtk2")
gwin <- gwindow()
group <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, spacing = 0, container = gwin)
gtable(iris, container = group)
```

I found nothing (maybe i looked bad...) in the gWidgets doc and examples.

It works using the tcltk guiToolkit :..

```
options("guiToolkit" = "tcltk")
gwin <- gwindow()
group <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, spacing = 0, container = gwin)
gtable(iris, container = group)
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: add `expand=TRUE, fill=TRUE` in the gtable constructor. That should do it.

Comment: Too easy ... It works perfectly
Thank You very much

Comment: @jverzani I'm using `gWidgets2` and these options have no effect. There's always only one line displayed... not always actually, that seems to depend on the "depth" of the widget (child of child of child...).